# How can I drain all the water in the ocean in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, mcedit

I recently had an idea for a video I could make where I show what minecraft looks like when all the water was drained from the ocean. However doing it by normal means would take months to complete. Is there something I could do in mcedit or a command to get rid of all the water in the ocean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the command you want:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ repeating_command_block{auto:1,Command:"execute at @p run fill ~-15 ~-15 ~-15 ~15 ~15 ~15 air replace water"}
```

This puts down a command block that constantly replaces water around you with air.

That's the answer to your question. But the solution for your problem is:

Create a customised world with the water level at the lowest possible value.

Comment: +1 for adding the solution for the problem. Sometimes what we need is not actually what we ask for.

Comment: That's why it's always good to say what your main goal is.